# how to insert a span tag inside a button tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting a div element using querySelector and able to change the button name, but I want to insert a span tag as well.

```
var element = document.querySelector("#secondselectionbox"); //This is the div element

(element.childNodes[1].textContent = "Standard");  //Name of the button
```

I want to wrap the "Standard" in span tag.

I have tried to create a span using createElement, but that just appends the span to the list buttons instead of inside the button.

Answer (score 4):

Tell me if this works the way you want:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#secondselectionbox");

element.innerHTML += "<span>Standard</span>";
```

Comment: Had to make some minor change to your answer. The below snippet worked for me. Thank you for the direction. (element.childNodes[1].innerHTML = ""); (element.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "<span>Standard</span>")

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `<span>` node using `createElement`.
2. Change the `innerText` (*or `textContent`*) of the `<span>` node.
3. Append the `<span>` node to the selected `element`.

OR

You can also set the `innerHTML` of the selected `element` but I would avoid doing that.

Check the code snippet below:

```js
var element = document.querySelector("#secondselectionbox"); //This is the div element

const span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerText = "Standard"
element.appendChild(span);

// You can also set the innerHTML, but I would avoid doing that
// element.innerHTML = "<span>Standard</span>"
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondselectionbox"></div>
```

**UPDATE: Based on OP's comment**

If your div has multiple buttons inside them and you wish to add a span element inside each of those buttons, you can simply loop over all the child nodes of the div and if the child is a button you can append a span to it.

```js
var element = document.querySelector("#secondselectionbox"); //This is the div element

Array.from(element.children).forEach(btn => {
  if (btn.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = "Standard"
    btn.appendChild(span);
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondselectionbox">
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <p>Not a button</p>
  <button></button>
  <p>Not a button</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the element contains a list of buttons, so appending span just appends it to the list of buttons.

Comment: @myesteriousbot I've updated my answer, please take a look. Let me know if it solves your problem! Thanks